# google maps api v3 polylines not showing up in visual basic webbrowser control

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Polylines in Google maps v2 worked fine in visual basic web browser.  Now Google maps v3 returns an error "Unable to set property 'lat' of undefined or null reference".  The application is running as a Javascript html file from a visual basic program.  When I execute the script directly in Internet Explorer the polylines work just fine.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyDGYPgYpwZ4ZQCLCAujetDwArlVBC_S9TI&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.70245,-95.7185)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);



 //<!var image = 'http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/wht-circle.png';  
  var image = 'http://google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-circle.png';
  var DC = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.70245,-95.7185),
      map: map,
      icon: image
  });

  var image = "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_gray.png";
  var Customer = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(31.291982, -95.821856),
      map: map,
      icon: image
  });

 var Customer = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.291982, -105.821856),
      map: map,
      icon: image
  });

  var polyline = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(36.70245,-95.7185),
    new google.maps.LatLng(31.291982, -95.821856),
  ];
  var polyline_overlay = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: polyline,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  polyline_overlay.setMap(map);

  var polyline = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(36.70245,-95.7185),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.291982, -105.821856),
  ];
  var polyline_overlay = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: polyline,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  polyline_overlay.setMap(map);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser and version does your control emulate? Have you tried either of the [other non-experimental versions of the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)? Sometimes things "break" in the experimental version.

Answer (score 0):

for starters, might remove the comma after the last coordinate:
    var polyline = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(36.70245,-95.7185),
        new google.maps.LatLng(41.291982, -105.821856),
      ];

should be:
    var polyline = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(36.70245,-95.7185),
        new google.maps.LatLng(41.291982, -105.821856)  //remove comma here
      ];